# CSS positioning - how to fix a load issue

Tags: html, css, load, css-position

I have two css buttons on my homepage that are have an absolute position on them relative to an image. The problem I'm having is that they load a lot faster than the image does, so for a split second upon loading the page, the buttons are floating out in la la land until the image loads and they fall in to line.

Is there a simple fix to this or do I have to totally redo the positioning?

Comment: the image is your positioning container? can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to hide the buttons (display:none) initially, and use javascript/jquery to show onload.

jQuery example is to do:

```
$('#ImgReferenced').on('load',function(){
    $('input[button]').show();
});
```

But the same can be done in javascript with an onload eventhandler.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the width and height attributes `<img ... width="xxx" height="yyy">`on the image element? That's how the browser can "reserve space" for the image and know its dimensions before the image is loaded. It needs this so it can draw something relative to the image.